# Android Web driver giving error for android sdk 2.3 and 2.2 while running android test for a samplegoogletest code

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium, sdk, webdriver

I am trying to run the simple code to open a google in emulator, type some keys and submit it. But everytime the test is failing. I have tried it with SDK 2.3 as well as SDK 2.2. For both the SDK's i am getting different error for the same code.

Error for SDK 2.3 is: Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.
Error for SDK 2.2 is: java.lang.NosuchmethodError (this error occurs for driver.sendkeys()).

Following is the error logcat for SDK 2.2:

```
 08-07 17:51:02.767: E/AndroidRuntime(3556): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 17:51:02.767: E/AndroidRuntime(3556): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.MotionEvent.setSource
08-07 17:51:02.767: E/AndroidRuntime(3556):     at org.openqa.selenium.android.EventSender$1.run(EventSender.java:55)
08-07 17:51:02.767: E/AndroidRuntime(3556):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-07 17:51:02.767: E/AndroidRuntime(3556):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-07 17:51:02.767: E/AndroidRuntime(3556):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-07 17:51:02.767: E/AndroidRuntime(3556):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-07 17:51:02.767: E/AndroidRuntime(3556):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 17:51:02.767: E/AndroidRuntime(3556):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-07 17:51:02.767: E/AndroidRuntime(3556):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-07 17:51:02.767: E/AndroidRuntime(3556):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-07 17:51:02.767: E/AndroidRuntime(3556):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Following is the sample code for opening google:

```
public void testGoogleWorks() 
    {

        System.out.println("in test google works");
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println("after driver . get");
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        System.out.println("after search box");

        searchBox.sendKeys("Cheese!");
        System.out.println("after sendkeys");
        searchBox.submit();
        System.out.println("after submit");

        String title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("after driver . gettitle");
        assertTrue("Got title: " + title, title.contains("Google"));
        assertTrue(driver.findElements(By.name("Testing")).size() > 1);
}
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

MotionEvent.setSource method was introduced in honeycomb. I believe you are running a sample from 3.0 + on previous sdks.